# Error using ApplyFilter to create a search box in a form in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I've been trying to do a Search-Box in a `form` in Access 2013. I get it to work the first time but after I close and open the database I got a message that says: 
`The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query`
It also gives the advice to use `SelectObject to select the form before executing ApplyFilter`. I tried that but it gives another error.

Here's how I did the search box:

1. I created a query, it works.
2. Selected the query and created a form - split form!
3. Then I created a`text box`, named it "nombre_cliente" and then added a button.
4. Selected button > properties > on click > Macro:
   ApplyFilter:

Name of the form: "Trabajos Totales" which is the name of the query, actually.

Where clause: `[Cliente] Like "*" & [Form]![Trabajos Totales]![nombre_cliente] & "*"`

After that I try it out and it works like a charm. As I have a main manu, I select the title of the form and added to the navigation menu. And suddenly it stops working with the above error.

Any ideas why is this happening? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the filter is not active when you load the form.
In form properties set FilterOnLoad to false.
Or wirte a macro that clears the filterValue on the onLoad Event.